# How to set dynamic `home` and `siteurl` in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I config the multi-language setting dynamically using the `locale` filter. Which fetch the sub-domain name to determine the language.

```
function load_custom_language($locale) {
    // get the locale code according to the sub-domain name.
    // en.mysite.com => return `en`
    // zh.mysite.com => return `zh_CN`
    // tw.mysite.com => return `zh_TW`
    // etc..
}
add_filter('locale', 'load_custom_language');
```

---

That works for the index page, but when I redirect to another page, because of the settings of `home` and `siteurl`, it always redirects my site to the original one (`www.mysite.com`).

So I'm curious to find a dynamic way to filter the `home` and `siteurl` according to the request, because I might use more than one sub-domain for mysite and I have only one settings for the two settings.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can override the admin settings in the wp-config.php file.
So if you want something dynamic, the following should work:

```
//presumes server is set up to deliver over https

define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

This needs to added before the line

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

or else you may have problems with some content using the wrong URLs, especially theme files.

Comment: That doesn't work, that turned my site into a Redirection Loop. May that code be placed somewhere after that?

Comment: hmm, it should work. If you set a fixed value instead of using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` does it work?

Comment: I set a fixed value, then it cause a `redirection loop`

Comment: Ok, well this is pretty much straight out of the wordpress codex :http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php (scroll down a bit), and works on my local copy, so i guess you have some other redirection (maybe a plugin?) interfering

Comment: I've found another nice way using filter myself. But thank you anyway.

Comment: You get a redirect loop because it tries to redirect you to `https://` but you force `http://` in this config. Just replace `http` with `https`, or make the protocol dynamic as well.

Comment: @djboris yes, this needs updating for 2022. For now i'll change to hardcoded https, but feel free to add an answer / edit mine with dynamic protocol

Answer (score 4):

I've found another pretty way to achieve the work:

After I checked for the source code of the kernel, I found that there are distinct filters called `option_xxx` on each options.

So, for my task, I tried to use the `option_siteurl` and `option_home` filter to hold that options to load, just to prevent the option to load, maintaining the `SERVER_NAME` it has:

```
function replace_siteurl($val) {
    return 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
add_filter('option_siteurl', 'replace_siteurl');
add_filter('option_home', 'replace_siteurl');
```

Using this way, it has no need to change the `wp_config.php` file, and can be easily add to a theme or a plugin.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to implement a similar approach for modifying the URL of emojii js in WP: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251910/modify-default-url-for-wp-includes-js-wp-embed-min-jsver-4-6-1, but not only it did not change the default URL, but also introduced issues with intermittent 500 error messages in loading the page. What is your view on it? Are filters a good option?

Answer (score 2):

To **set dynamically the domain and as well as the protocol** (*http* or *https*), use:

```php
// Identify the relevant protocol for the current request
$protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https" : "http";

// Set SITEURL and HOME using a dynamic protocol.
define('WP_SITEURL', $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```