# Wordpress site serve to both http and https at the same time with different domains

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, amazon-cloudfront

I need to serve my Wordpress website to a http://"specific domain" and to a https://"specific domain at the same time". I know i can define the wp site url and wp home like this,

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

But in my case i need to load https:// as well due to mixed content issue in Wordpress after installing a SSL certificate on my domain. Actually i'm using Cloudfront with SSL certificate for the users.

If i explain furthermore, Cloudfront't origin website is the same website without SSL. Such as,

Cloudfront origin website:

```
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/
```

User accessing website:

```
https://www.maindomain.com/
```

So i need to use the same website with both http and https options with two different domains as mentioned. Hope a good solution to solve this issue.

Comment: I don't believe you can configure wordpress to do this. IN the past, you might use .htaccess to redirect http requests to the https endpoint, but you should really only use https for all connections. What is the use case for that subdomain that has http access?

Comment: that subdomain is the origin site for the AWS Cloudfront. I got SSL certificate from AWS and integrated SSL through Cloudfront.

Comment: You can set a dynamic `wp_siteurl` and `wp_home`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014426/how-to-set-dynamic-home-and-siteurl-in-wordpress

Comment: This has done already

Answer (score 0):

Since it is 2018, it's more than valid – proper form, even – to use an entirely `https` workflow. This method will rewrite your existing `http` files to `https` locally, thereby avoiding any major restructuring of your server. So an added bonus here, is that you can kiss any "mixed content" issues goodbye.

If you do not have an `.htaccess` file already, then create one on the html root. Add these `rewrite` lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks for this code. But unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I'm using Wordpress

Comment: My purpose is to serve https site in-front of AWS Cloudfront and Cloudfront origin is http site. So at the same time website behaves as a http site and a https site. And my SSL certificate is issued by Amazon. So i'm integrating the SSL certificate through AWS Cloudfront. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: @CodeCanyon I'm not sure I do get the idea. When I point my browser to any AWS Cloudfront page, it has `https` all over it. However you say, "Cloudfront origin is http site". Question: What happens if you take the URL, and _manually_ add the "s" so that `http` becomes `https` in your browser address field? Second question: Are you using any specific WP "template"?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue. Issue was from Cloudfront side. Once enabled cookies and whitelist headers, solved the issue. Assume someone else will help this solution.